# Is there a way to query JSON column in SQL Server ignoring capitalization of keys?

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, azure

I am trying to query a JSON column that has mixed capitalization.  For instance, some rows have keys that are all lower case like below:

```
{"name":"Screening 1","type":"template","pages":[{"pageNumber":1,...}
```

However, some of the rows have keys that are capitalized on its first letter like this:

```
{"Type":"template","Name":"Screening2","Pages":[{"PageNumber":1,...}
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server seems to only supports JSON path system that is case sensitive.  Therefore, I can't query on all rows successfully.  If I use lower case path like '$.pages' in a query like below:

```
SELECT ST.Id AS Screening_Tool_Id
    , ST.Name AS Screening_Tool_Name
    , ST.Description AS Screening_Tool_Description
    , COUNT(JSON_VALUE (SRQuestions.value, '$.id'))  AS Question_Specific_Id

FROM dbo.ScreeningTemplate AS ST
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(ST.Workflow, '$.pages') AS SRPages
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(SRPages.Value, '$.sections') AS SRSections
```

I miss any row that has capitalized keys.  Is there any way to query all rows ignoring their capitalization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to MS, looks like you're stuck with a case-sensitive query:

> When OPENJSON parses a JSON array, the function returns the indexes of
>   the elements in the JSON text as keys.+ The comparison used to match
>   path steps with the properties of the **JSON expression is**
>   **case-sensitive** and collation-unaware (that is, a BIN2 comparison).
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql

If the only variations are in the capitalization of the first character, you could try to work around this limitation by creating queries with the variants and `UNION` the results together.

Comment: I was thinking about using UNION as well, and it seems like the best way at the moment.  It will be better than re-writing all the JSON data.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you can just lower the json:

```
COUNT(JSON_VALUE (lower(SRQuestions.value), '$.id'))  AS Question_Specific_Id
```

Comment: This is a good solution if you do not have case sensitive data. In my case, values in the JSON were numbers, so it was fine to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use openjson. Instead of

```sql
    JSON_VALUE (SRQuestions.value, '$.id')
```

you can write

```sql
    (select Value 
       from openjson( SRQuestions.value ) 
      where [Key] collate latin1_general_ci = 'id')
```

You must use a Case-Insensitive "_ci" collation here. "UTF8_General_CI" works too, as does "database_default" if the database uses a CI collation.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but I came across this when googling a similar issue so I will chip in with my solution:

```
SELECT @pb = PB from  
   OPENJSON(@PropertyBagsAsJson, '$."$values"') 
    WITH (                        
          PbId1 nvarchar(MAX) 'lax $.Id',
          PbId2 nvarchar(MAX) 'lax $.id',             
          PB nvarchar(MAX)  '$' AS JSON
    )
WHERE COALESCE(PbId1,PbId2) = @PropertyBagId
```

I hope that the example is clear. Basically I just add all possible casing of the property and then just use Coalesce to filter the results.